# Compact form for the solution of the equation $x^{k+1} =c$, where $c\in\mathbb{R}^+$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

As an exercise of my mathclass, I need to evaluate the solution of the equation
$$x^{k+1} =c,$$
where $c\in\mathbb{R}, c\ge 0$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
I proceed in this way.
If $k=0$, thus it is just a linear equation and $x=c$ is the only solution.
If $k=1$ it is a quadratic equation $x^2 =c$, which solutions are $x=\pm\sqrt{c}$.
I am in trouble about the cases for $k\ge 2$. I mean, I have to distinguish the cases for $k$ even and odd?
It is possible to find a solution that encloses all the cases for $k$?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What type of answer are you looking for? It would just be $\sqrt[k+1]{c}$ for odd $k$ and $\pm\sqrt[k+1]{c}$ for even $k$.

Comment: @UNOwen Shouldnt it be the opposite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use n-th roots of unity:

$$x^n = c \implies x = \sqrt[n]{c} \cdot \sqrt[n]{1}$$

where $\sqrt[n]{1} = e^{i\frac{2k\pi}{n}}$ for $k=0,1,2,...,n-1$ are exactly the n-th roots of unity.

Comment: gibster, I need just real solutions.

Comment: This is a real solution! :)

Comment: @daw I expected something a solution like the comment of UNOwen. It sounds i bit strange to me to involve the $n$-roots of unity.

Comment: You can always consider only the real nth roots of unity, namely 1 for odd $n$ and $\pm 1$ for even $n$.

Comment: @gibster sorry, I missed your comment. So it should be $x=c^{1/(k+1)}$ if $k$ is even and $x=\pm c^{1/(k+1)}$ if $k$ is odd, isn't it?

Comment: yes, since you have a +1.